# SSIS Merge Varying Columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Using SSIS, I am importing a .txt file, which for the most part if straight forward.

The file being imported has a set amount of columns up to a point, but there is a free text/comments field, which can repeat to unknown length, similar to below.

```
   "000001","J Smith","Red","Free text here"
   "000002","A Ball","Blue","Free text here","but can","continue"
   "000003","W White","Green","Free text here","but can","continue","indefinitely"
   "000004","J Roley","Red","Free text here"
```

What I would ideally like to do (within SSIS) is to keep the first three columns as singular columns, but to merge any free-text ones into a single column. i.e. Merge/concatenate anything which appears after the 'colour' column.

So when I load this into an SSMS table, it appears like:

```
000001 | J Smith | Red   | Free text here                                     |
000002 | A Ball  | Blue  | Free text here but can continue                    |
000003 | W White | Green | Free text here but can continue indefinitely       |
000004 | J Roley | Red   | Free text here                                     |
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any easy solution. You can try something like below:

**1. Load the complete raw data to a temp table (without any delimiter):**

**Steps:**

1. Create temp table in Execute SQL Task
2. Create a data flow task, with flat file source (with Ragged Right format) and
3. OLEDB destination (usint #temp table create in previous task)
4. Set the `delayValidation=True` for connection manager and DFT
5. Set `retainSameConnection=True` for connection manager

Refer [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/) to create temp table and using it.

**2. Create T-SQL to separate the 3 columns (something like below)**

> ```
> with col1 as (
>   Select 
>   [Val],
>   substring([Val], 1 ,charindex(',', [Val]) - 1) col1,
>   len(substring([Val], 1 ,charindex(',', [Val]))) + 1 col1Len
>   from #temp
> ), col2 as (
>   select 
>   [Val],
>   col1,
>   substring([Val], col1Len, charindex(',', [Val], col1Len) - col1Len) as col2,
>   charindex(',', [Val], col1Len) + 1 col2Len
>    from col1
> ) select col1, col2, substring([Val], col2Len, 200) as col3
> from col2
> ```

**T-SQL Output:**

```
col1    col2    col3
"000001"    "J Smith"   "Red","Free text here"
"000002"    "A Ball"    "Blue","Free text here","but can","continue"
"000003"    "W White"   "Green","Free text here","but can","continue","indefinitely"
```

**3. Use the above query in OLEDB source in different data flow task**

Replace double quotes (") as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun exercise:

Add a data flow

Add a Script Component (select Source)

Add 4 columns to Outputs ID, Name Color , FreeText all type string

edit script:

Paste the following namespaces up top:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
```

Paste the following code into CreateNewOutputRows:

```
    string strPath = @"a:\test.txt";  \\put your file path in here
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strPath);

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        //Code I stole to read CSV
        string delimeter = ",";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(String.Format("(\"[^\"]*\"|[^{0}])+", delimeter));
        var cols = rgx.Matches(line)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value.Trim().Trim('"'))
                      .Where(v => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v));
        //create a column counter
        int ctr = 0;

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        //Preset FreeText to empty string
        string FreeTextBuilder = String.Empty;

        foreach( string col in cols)
        {

            switch (ctr)
            {
                case 0: 
                    Output0Buffer.ID = col; 
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Output0Buffer.Name = col;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Output0Buffer.Color = col;
                    break;
                default:
                    FreeTextBuilder += col + " ";
                    break;
            }
            ctr++;
        }

        Output0Buffer.FreeText = FreeTextBuilder.Trim();

    }
```